# WCF default serializer do not serialize Dictionary<string,object> with null values

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, dictionary

I have  app that retrieve data from server via WCF (servicecontract interfaces, dataContracts,etc)

I have object `PackedObject`:

```
public class PackedObject
 {
    [DataMember]
    private String _objTypeName;

    [DataMember]
    private Guid _id;

    [DataMember]
    private Dictionary<string, object> _fields = new Dictionary<string,object>();

    ...
 }
```

I fill `_fields` Dictionary from DataRow as (column name) --> (value in that column)

Some cells in DataRow can be null.
The object with all non-null values in dictionary serializes and deserializes properly. But if value is null the service just stop serialization without any errors.
It doesn't stop working: My application still trying to repeat request to service and i see a new log information about this new requests in service.
Seems like `DataContractSerializer` doesn't want to serialize dictionary values with nulls(Other items with non-null values in dictionary serializes properly)

**What should i do to fix this?**

Comment: Would it not be better to just not populate null values into the dictionary?

Comment: Because `DataRow` is fetched from database, and some cells in db can be null.
Also i want to store records from all columns for one row in this dictionary, because later i will try to do something like `Guid  ParentId = (Guid)_fields["parentId"]??Guid.Empty()`.

Comment: can you show how you fill the Dictionary in code?

Comment: here it is
http://puu.sh/g5tGA/f172610121.png
http://puu.sh/g5tMu/3c1e2104d2.png 
http://puu.sh/g5tOv/ec3b974b74.png

Comment: Object is not a good candidate for a DTO. You should define the types you are expecting to be returned from the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to DataContract-class DataMember attribute. Then use KnownType attributes for expected types used for object. in the following example I use either int or bool in the collection :

```
[DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(int[]))]
    [KnownType(typeof(bool[]))]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        [DataMember]
        public object UsedForKnownTypeSerializationObject;

    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Parameters
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```